# Qt mdi windows not receiving mouse events

Tags: qt, mouseevent, mdi

Using the mdi example I added mouse events to mainwindow as:
protected:
I can receive right and middle button down but no left button or mouse move or button up events.
Help please.

```
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;

    void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        printf("mouse down\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        printf("mouse\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        printf("mouse up\n");
        fflush(stdout);``
    }
```

Comment: A typical reason for events not being received is that they have been accepted by another widget. Have you added the same overrides to the `QMdiArea` to test whether it is receiving them instead? With regard to `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent`, note that the property `mouseTracking` is `false` by default, so that move events will not be received. You can enable mouse tracking with `QWidget::setMouseTracking(true);`.

Comment: Also please be aware that if you don't accept the `mousePressEvent`, you will not get the moves and the release from this mouse interaction.